# Trying to thin out backup files but Get-ChildItem isn't returning usable list

Tags: arrays, powershell, powershell-3.0, get-childitem

We have a backup that runs every other day, but the files are large and we want to just remove every other one once we get a certain amount of backup files with our file signature.

I've tried this:

```
$Drive = "E:\temp\"
$deleteTime = -42;
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays($deleteTime)

#this is finding the correct files but I don't think it's really in an array
$temp1 = Get-ChildItem -Path $Drive -filter "*junk.vhd*" | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit} | Select -Expand Name

for($i=$temp1.GetLowerBound(0); $i -le $temp1.GetUpperBound(0); $i+=2) {

   Write-Host "removing $temp1[$i]"  #this is listing the entire array with a [0] for first one and the third [2] element also, whether I cast to an array or not

}
```

I tried this instead of the above (Get-ChildItem) line currently but it listed the entire set of junk files for [0] instead of just the first junk.vhd at [0]:

```
[array]$temp1 =@( Get-ChildItem -Path $Drive -filter "*junk.vhd*" | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit} | Foreach-Object {$_.Name} )
```

I tried this too:

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-42)
$list = (dir -Filter *junk.ps1 | where LastWriteTime -lt $limit).FullName
$count = $list.Length
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $count; $i += 2)
{
    Write-Verbose "[$i] $($list[$i])"
    #it's not getting in here because I'm not sure how 
    #to add the $Drive location and list is empty
}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion how to get an array of the filenames from $Drive location with the signature *junk.vhd so I can loop through them and remove every other one?

An internet search isn't turning much up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$deleteTime = -12;
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays($deleteTime)
$t = Get-ChildItem -Path $pwd -filter "p*.txt" | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit} | Select -Expand Name  

foreach ($a in $t) { Write-Host "Name : $a" }
```

What have I missed from what you were looking for?
(Obviously, you will need to maintain a counter and do some modulo arithmetic in the body of the foreach() statement... )

This works, too:

```
for($i=$t.GetLowerBound(0); $i -le $t.GetUpperBound(0); $i+=2) {  
   $n = $t[$i]  
   Write-Host "removing $n"    
}
```